# How to replace the first Fragment of ViewPager with another Fragment and be at the same position of the previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I'm using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in my app . I have 2 tabs in my ViewPager . I have the main 2 `Fragment` for the 2 tabs .
The first `Fragment` is like a form when user click submit , another `Fragment` appears to user and so on and be at the same position of the previous Fragment. I want to do that in the first Fragment (first position of my ViewPager) and keep the state of the previous fragment when I click back button . I hope that I posted my question in a right way

Here is my ViewPager

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".UI.Fragments.OnlineBookingModule.OnlineBookingFragment">

   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:background="@color/bg_nav"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is My `Pager Adapter`

```
public class BookingPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public BookingPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior,Context context) {
        super(fm, behavior);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0)
            return new NewBookingFragment();
        else
            return new FutureBookingFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position==0)
            return context.getString(R.string.new_booking);
        else
            return context.getString(R.string.future_booking);
    }
}
```

Here is how I setup my viewPager in my `Fragment`

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_booking, container, false);

        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        Preferences preferences = new Preferences();
        preferences.saveSmallDays(getActivity(),0);
        preferences.saveBigDays(getActivity(),0);
        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
        pagerAdapter = new BookingPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT,getActivity());
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You might be better of with  ViewPager2 https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2 as this " modifiable Fragment collections"

Comment: Can I replace the first position (first fragment) with another fragment with the ViewPager 2 ?

Comment: @Andrew and please what is the difference between ViewPager and ViewPager 2

Comment: Viewpager is an old implementation of this type of widget with a lots of it being  deprecated, with Viewpager2 being a new implementation based on top of a Recyclerview and "ViewPager2 replaces ViewPager, addressing most of its predecessor’s pain-points, including right-to-left layout support, vertical orientation, modifiable Fragment collections, etc." And just like a Recyclerview you can add or remove items.